# how can i add swipe control of camera angle with Cardboard SDK in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe, google-cardboard, 360-degrees

I'm developing an **iOS 360** video player with **Cardboard SDK** in **Unity**.
I've already made head movement control of camera angle working. But now I'd like to control the camera angle by swiping of fingers.
Is there already such a feature with in the SDK or do I have to do the revision of its code.
What do I do? Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).